# Extract paragraph from txt file using keyword pythong

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hi all im new to python I would really appreicate you help .

I have a paragraph as shown below, you can see each paragraph is separated by an empty line 
I want to write code where I can search for keyword e.g . "MBA"
and the program will find the paragraph that contains this word and save it.

> MBA,At the center of ADSM’s MBA is the Signature Learning Experience
>   (SLE), which runs the length of the three-semester program. This
>   hands-on experience entails small teams of students creating and
>   developing an entrepreneurial project. As a result, students receive
>   first-hand experiences in entrepreneurial decision-making while
>   integrating the diverse knowledge areas of MBA core knowledge. The
>   focus of the SLE is not only on the development of the business skills
>   necessary to be successful business leaders and entrepreneurs, but
>   also gives students the skill sets necessary to manage themselves and
>   others in this context. The SLE also emphasizes the importance of
>   strong communication skills, an ethical and societal approach to
>   decision-making, and independent project development skills.
>
> MSQBE,The Master of Science in Quality and Business Excellence program
>   seeks to educate new cohorts of entrepreneurial business leaders with
>   professional education in modern theory and practice of Quality and
>   Business Excellence. The program supports the pillars of the Abu Dhabi
>   2030 Vision, especially those directed at the promotion of a large,
>   empowered private sector and a sustainable knowledge-based economy.
>   The MS QBE program allows students to gain an in-depth understanding
>   of international quality frameworks, issues in business excellence,
>   the various quality award frameworks and their practical applications
>   in the workplace. The program will equip graduates to implement
>   practical approaches and techniques of Quality and Business Excellence
>   and address the needs of the employment market, not only in Abu Dhabi
>   but also across the UAE and into international markets.
>
> MSLOD,The Master of Science in Leadership and Organizational
>   Development program is designed specifically for students wishing to
>   develop their skills and understanding of the Leadership and
>   Organizational Development activities undertaken within the context of
>   the evolving and complex world of today’s business environment. The MS
>   LOD program provides students with a high-quality professional
>   education in modern theory and practice of Leadership and
>   Organizational Development. Graduates from the program would be able
>   to analyze, solve problems and effectively respond to and manage rapid
>   technological and organizational changes prevalent in the modern
>   business environment. This program supports the pillars of the Abu
>   Dhabi 2030 Vision, especially those directed at the promotion of a
>   large empowered private sector, and a sustainable knowledge-based
>   economy. The degree provides the underpinning knowledge to students
>   wishing to follow a career in the fields of leadership and
>   organizational development.
>
> MSBA,The Master of Science in Business Analytics (MSBA) program seeks
>   to educate new cohorts of business leaders who will contribute to the
>   socio-economic development of the emirate of Abu Dhabi. The program
>   contributes to several of the seven areas of ongoing economic policy
>   of Vision 2030, especially to ‘build an open, efficient, effective and
>   globally integrated business environment’, ‘develop a highly skilled,
>   highly productive workforce’, and ‘drive significant improvement in
>   the efficiency of the labour market’. The Master of Science in
>   Business Analytics (MSBA) program is designed specifically for
>   students wishing to develop their analytics skills and solve business
>   problems through using analytical tools and methods. The program will
>   enable professionals to develop or enhance their skills in managing
>   business issues in the context of large data sets. This program will
>   benefit business and IT professionals in a range of sectors such as
>   finance and consulting, logistics, marketing, and healthcare.

As you can see each paragraph is separated by an empty line.

I managed to write a code where I can save paragraph but I couldn't do it using keywords.

my code

```
file = open("programs.txt", "r")
op = ''
start = 0
cntr=0

   for x in file.read().split("\n"):
    if(x == "*****************"):

            with open(str(cntr) + '.txt','w') as opf:
                opf.write(op)
                opf.close()
                op = ''

    else:
        op = op + '\n' + x
```

Comment: You should investigate how to find a substring of a string in python.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.find(substring)` to search the pattern in paragraph. 
Like:

```
f = open("programs.txt", "r")
for number, paragraph in enumerate(f.read().split("\n\n"), 1):
    print(number)
    print(paragraph)
    pattern = "MBA"
    if paragraph.find(pattern) != -1:
        print("save to file") 
    else:
        print("don't save to file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if `x` is a substring of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`.

```
with open("programs.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read();
result = [par for par in text.split('\n\n') if 'MBA' in par]
```

.. then write the list `result` to a file.